# Set Range protection weekly time-based trigger

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to write a script that will protect a varying range in sheets weekly. I have figured out the weekly locking and trigger to initiate it. However, Each week needs a new range. If week 1 was;

```
var range = sheet.getRange(4, 5, 5, 6);
```

week 2 would need;

```
var range = sheet.getRange(10, 5, 5, 6);
```

and so on. So only my Row input will need changing based off the week the trigger is actived.

Complete Script is currently as follows:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Multiple'); //INSERT SHEET NAME HERE


function lockRange(row, col){
  var range = sheet.getRange(10, 5, 5, 6);

  // Create protection object. Set description, anything you like.
  var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Date1');

 // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
 // permission comes from a group, the script will throw an exception upon removing the group.
 var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
 protection.addEditor(me);
 protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
 if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
   protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It looks that you are looking for help on the implementation of an algorithm in Google Apps Script. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts (as is suggested in [ask]) regarding how set a row number based on the week (tip: look for JavaScript questions )

Comment: You should set a datum somewhere for the start of the weekly range (say Monday 1 June 2020), then calculate how many whole weeks have passed since then to calculate the first parameter passed to *getRange*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can store the next week in the Script's properties using `PropertiesService`.*

#### Code Modification:

```js
function lockRange(row, col){
  var week = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("week");

  if (!week) {
    week = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("week", 4)
  }
  else {
    week = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("week", parseInt(week) + 6)
  }  

  week = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("week");

  var range = sheet.getRange(parseInt(week), 5, 5, 6);

  // continue your code...
}

function clearProperties() {
  // run this function ONCE to clear any properties that are being stored in
  // the script from testing/previous runs.
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteAllProperties();
}
```

#### References:

- [Properties Service | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties)
- [Class Properties | Apps Script | Google Develovers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties)

Comment: I am currently caught by a syntax error- unexpected token 'else'

Comment: @DStutz You need to close the if block with a `}`

Comment: TypeError: PropertiesService.getProperty is not a function
is the next error I am encountering

Comment: The full method is `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty`

Comment: Exception: Cannot convert 'ScriptProperties' to int.

Comment: For your script above it would be the line: var range = sheet.getRange(week, 5, 5, 6);

Comment: Gotcha - the variable `week` needs to be recalled. I also added in a `parseInt()` function to make sure the range is correctly obtained, please see the updated code.

Comment: Also, if you have run variants of the code above, run `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteAllProperties()` *once*, in its own function, so that the stored properties are cleared and will not interfere with your sheet.